# What are the cases where a TX is not sent to the Notary Service?

Tags: corda

What are the situations a transaction is not submitted to the Notary service? Although the progress tracker shows notary steps, we noted in some cases the transaction is not really sent to the Notary service. (e.g. State creation with no time window).

Comment: If there are no Inputs or Time Window in the Transaction then it's not sent to the notary .

Comment: So, a validating notary would not validate a transaction in these situations, right? Is it possible to force it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Corda 3.3, if Tx has no inputs and no time window then it's not sent to the notary for signature.

But with Corda 4, as I can see in the master, in addition to the above two conditions, it is sent to the notary, in case a reference state is present :

https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/838c99c6e48788a21f7ca25aaee4c04cffb980c9/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/FinalityFlow.kt#L164